# Generalization of Beck's theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-geometry

**[Beck's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck's_theorem)** is a classical result in discrete geometry which describes about the geometry of points in the plane. The result states that a finite collections of points in the plane fall into one of two extremes; one where a large fraction of points lie on a single line, and one where a large number of lines are needed to connect all the points.

Formally, the statement of the theorem is as follows:

**Theorem:** Let $S$ be a set of $n$ points in the plane. If at most $(n-k)$ points lie on any line for some $0 \leq k < n-2$, then there exist $\Omega(nk)$ lines determined by the points of $S$.

Now, my question is that if the generalization/variation of the above result is known in the case of higher dimension $(dim\geq 3)$?

Comment: Except few sentences all other sentences of the question are exact copy of wiki. Provide a quotation if you copy that amount of text from somewhere else (not from your own). Finally why you didn't see this? "Take for example a set of 2n points in R3 all lying on two skew lines. Assume that these two lines are each incident to n points. Such a configuration of points spans only 2n planes. Thus, a trivial extension to the hypothesis for point sets in Rd is not sufficient to obtain the desired result.", that says generalization first needs a good new definition rather than the trivial ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking if the same statement holds true or not in higher dimensions, it does. Just project all the points to a random 2-dimensional plane.

Another natural generalization is to consider hyperplanes instead of lines. Here, you have Beck's "other" theorem:

> **Theorem**: For any $d \geq 2$, there are constants $\beta_d, \gamma_d \in (0,1/2]$ such that for any set $P$ of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, at least one of the following holds:
>
> - a hyperplane contains at least $\beta_d n$ points of $P$
> - the $d$-tuples of $P$ span at least $\gamma_d n^d$ distinct hyperplanes.

Here, a hyperplane is a $(d-1)$-dimensional flat. For $d=2$, this is essentially what you stated. The restriction that $\beta_d \leq 1/2$ is from the example of having two skew lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing $n/2$ points each, where the number of spanned planes is $n$. For more, see: [http://www.cs.elte.hu/~elekes/Abstracts/elest.ps](http://www.cs.elte.hu/%7Eelekes/Abstracts/elest.ps)